# dynamic height scrollable div

Tags: html, css

Ideally using CSS only I want a scollable div that is dynamic in height.

Mockup of layout...

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .page {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;  
        }
        .top{
            height: 100px; background-color: Gray;
        }
        .middle {
            height: 150px; background-color: Green;
        }
        .bottom {
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
    <div class="top">
        top
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        second
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        This one I want to be dynamic in height (stretch from here to the bottom of the window). <br />
        And scroll if the content if its bigger than the height allowed in the window.
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
        <p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p><p>a line</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.bottom is the div i want to stretch to the bottom of the browser...then scroll if need be.

--UPDATE:
whipped up this bit of javascript which does a pretty good job ... but would like a purely css solution really??

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"           type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SetScrollableDivHeight($(".bottom"));
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        SetScrollableDivHeight($(".bottom"));
    });
    function SetScrollableDivHeight(div) {
        var top = div.position().top;
        var windowH = $(document).height();
        var remaining = windowH - top;

        div.height(remaining - 25);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: *"so i have something like"* um, how about telling us what you *really* have? The real mark-up and css, preferably with a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to illustrate. Also you 'want to start here be sized to the bottom of the window'? Fine, but you need to define what, or where, 'here' **is.**

Comment: Fair point David, although I've never seen or used JS fiddle.
The reason I didn't post the whole page is its not really my place to be putting in the public eye.
What I have is very simple...essentially content at the top of n height, then a div which I want (if poss with css) to dynamically size to the bottom of the window and scroll if required.  if the window is resized...the div with either scroll still or not, but still stretch to the bottom of the window.

Comment: create a demo page to show you...hope this makes it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Per the code above:

```
.page { ... height:100%;... }
.bottom { height:100%; overflow:auto; }
```

As long as it's parent has a height property `.bottom` will expand only to the height of its parent. That also applies to `.page`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following common pattern to solve your issue.

Put blocks in a flex container (`display: flex`) that takes the full page height (`height: 100vh`) and displays items vertically (`flex-direction: column`).

Add `overflow-y: auto` to the block you want to make scrollable.

Here is a code snippet. If you put long content into *main* (longer than page's height), the block gets a scroll.

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #FFECD1;
}

.main {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #FFD195;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="main">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

*Extra tips*

1. In the example above, the scrollable block (*main*) takes as much height as it needs depending on the size of content. Do you want the scrollable div to take all the available space even if it has not enough content? Then add the css property `flex-grow: 1;` to it.
2. You can use this pattern on any level of your html tree. If you apply it to a nested container, set *height* to *100%* instead of *100vh*. 100vh means that it will take the height of the screen and works for the whole page level. But you will need the actual height of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the size you want to your div and then you must add the `overflow: auto` css style.

For example, add the `scrollable` class to your div and add the following style to your css :

```
.scrollable {
   overflow: auto;
}
```

As soon as the content of your div is too big your its size, scrollbars will appear. You can force the scrollbar appearance with others value than auto, see : http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: yeah ok - but I i don't want to set the height of the div.  I want it to dynamically size to the bottom on the window.
If the content is too long, scroll bars will appear, if they resize their browser window, my div will stretch to the bottom and decide again if scroll bars are required.

Comment: Without the structure of your page it's impossible to give you a solution for sizing the div to the window height. But maybe this stackoverflow answer could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181597/div-100-of-window-height